# $\lim_{h\to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_h(x)-g(x)|^2dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, sequence-of-function

I can do (a) and (b), but I cannot do (c). I have attempted to use $$f_n(x)=\frac{f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}},$$ but I do not know how to proceed.

> (a) If $f(x) \in L^2(X)$ and $\mu(X)<\infty$, show that $f(x) \in L^1(X)$.
>
> (b) If $f(x)$, $x f(x) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, show that $f(x) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.
>
> (c) If $f(x)$, $g(x) \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and
> $$\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|f_h(x)-g(x)\right|^2 d x=0,$$
> where
> $$f_h(x):=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \quad \text { for any } h \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\},$$
> show that
> $$f(x)=\int_{[0, x]} g(t) d t+C
> $$for some constant $C$.

Comment: Something like Fatou lemma should give existence of lower limit of the ratio and its value should be $g(x)$ almost eeverywhere. Then, since this lower limit is the same (for given x) the limit in fact exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $g$ is the $L^2$-derivative of a function $f\in L^2$, then integrating $g$ gives $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276987/if-g-is-the-l2-derivative-of-a-function-f-in-l2-then-integrating-g-gi)

Comment: @Salcio I cannot see how your comment was related to the question.

Comment: The Fatou lemma says that integral from lower limit is less or equal lower limit of integral. So, you fix (for a moment) $h_n-> 0$ and use the lemma. You get that lower limit of the ration is $g(x)$ almost everywhere. This is true for any $h_n$ so the ration in fact has limit and the limit is $g(x)$. Hence $f(x)$ has derivative (almost everywhere) and it is $g(x)$.

Comment: We readily have (without Fatou) $\int_0^x|f_{h_n}-g|\to0$ but that does not imply $f_{h_n}\to g$ a.e. on $[0,x]$ (only a subsequence of $(f_{h_n}).$ And even if you succeed (by another method) to prove that $f'=g$ a.e., this is not sufficient to conclude.(look at the proposed duplicate). @Salcio

Comment: No, because for any $h_n$ limit not only exists but it is $g(x)$. This implies that the ratio has limit and it is $g(x)$.

Comment: Again: 1) Even limit in $L^1([0,x])$ (which is stronger than what you get with Fatou) only implies limit almost everywhere *of a subsequence*, 2) $f'=g$ almost everywhere would anyway not be sufficient to get $f(x)$ as an integral of $g.$ @Salcio